# Debug.Fail and Debug.Assert

Tags: .net, debugging

I have a question about the Debug.Fail method which puzzles me. It's from a MeassureUp test and goes like this:

To improve the reliability of your code, you want to verify an important value and stop execution if the value is not set properly. However, you want to stop execution only during debugging. You do not want users with release versions of your application to experience problems.

Which method should you use?

- Debug.Assert (my answer)
- Debug.Flush
- Debug.Fail (correct answer according to MeassureUp test)
- Debug.Indent

I answered Debug.Assert because it has a boolean condition as a parameter, which means it can verify a value. Debug.Fail only has strings as parameters for whatever message should be output. But here is the official reasoning:

- Debug.Fail causes the debugger to break at the line of code and output a failure message.
- Debug.Assert evaluates a condition and displays a message, but it does not interrupt processing.
- Debug.Flush flushes the debug output buffer.
- Debug.Indent controls the output formatting.

What do they mean by that the Debug.Assert "does not interrupt processing"? Both Debug.Assert and Debug.Fail gives a similar popup windows with Abort, Retry and Ignore buttons. Furthermore, Debug.Assert evaluates an expression.

Is the official answer wrong including their reasoning or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's just no difference.  Debug.Assert() calls Fail() when the condition is false.  So there's no difference either between Assert() and an if-statement that calls Fail().

I'd suggest you find a better web site.

Comment: Ok, thanks. The practice test came with the book for the 70-536 exam in .NET Foundation. But there seems to be a few errors in it.

Comment: These books always have a huge errata.  Just google it to find it.

Answer (score 1):

I use `Debug.Fail()` typically in `switch/default:` statements where `default:` should never occur (in addition to throwing an exception or whatever other error handling)